# SOC 2 Type 1 Report for Salesforce via Python

Tags: python, salesforce, report

How can I download the SOC 2 Type 1 report from compliance.salesforce.com via Python API or SDK? Here is the report URL:
https://compliance.salesforce.com/en/documents/a005A00000uKyHxQAK

Tried resources from:
[Salesforce: Download Reports via URL in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135216/salesforce-download-reports-via-url-in-r)
but, no luck. It re-directs to the main page after login.